# how to discard a change in magit from spacemacs

Tags: magit, spacemacs

In a normal emacs (not spacemacs), discard change is bound to key of "k", then in spacemacs, base on the following information.

http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html

On the other hand, anything originally bound to k will be found on K, since k is reserved but K is not. If there is a binding on K, that will be moved to C-k.

But when I press K, it pops us a helm buffer to let me select a file to ingore in git.

Comment: Spacemacs is using this package for evilifying magit: https://github.com/justbur/evil-magit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discard command is bound to `x`.

You can check key bindings by `?` in magit-status buffer as below.

[image]